# I can't share a content from my iOS app to the Facebook when Facebook app is installed

Tags: ios, objective-c, slcomposeviewcontroller

```
if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook])
    {
        imageUser.hidden=NO;
//            [imageUser sendSubviewToBack:_horizontalScrollView];

        SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];


        UIImage *goImage=[[UIImage alloc]init];
        goImage=[self scaleImage:image123];

        [controller setInitialText:@"Check out my pic from "];
        [controller addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.awesomeapp.com"]];
        [controller addImage:goImage];
        imageUser.hidden=YES;

        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];
    }
```

I have gone through many stackoverflow questions and tried almost all. Some users reported it as bug, If so do we have any other way through which I can achieve my goal. It works like charm when Facebook app is not there but when the app is there this won't work :

```
    [controller addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.awesomeapp.com"]];
```

Please help me achieve my goal. Thanks in advance.

Comment: tried to add the http:// at start of the url ?

Answer (score 0):

I too headed up with is problem,some how i managed with FBSDKShareKit

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://"]]) {
        FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
        NSString * UrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.google.co.in/"];
                                NSString * Subject = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"FBSDKShareKit is an alternative to this issue"];
        content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:UrlString];
        content.contentTitle = @"FBSDKShareKit";
        content.contentDescription = Subject;
        content.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/58832_300x300.jpg"];
        FBSDKShareDialog *dialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc] init];
        dialog.fromViewController = self;
        dialog.shareContent = content;
        dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogModeFeedBrowser;
        [dialog show];
}else{
    //Go with your own method to share in FaceBook
}
```

In my pod file:

```
pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 4.6.0'
```

**dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogModeFeedBrowser** it opens a fbShareDialog within your app which consist of all given datas.
Try some other alternatives for mode such as **FBSDKShareDialogModeShareSheet,FBSDKShareDialogModeBrowser,FBSDKShareDialogModeWeb...** it may also help you. I found **FBSDKShareDialogModeFeedBrowser** as satisfying. Try it,Let me know whether it works or not.

Comment: Do we have any other alternatives other than using FBSDK?

Comment: I too tried for other alternatives but no luck.At last ended with FBSDK,i don't think so there is other better ways to go.FB does not want to pre-fill contents while sharing.[link](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#control) Check point3 on above link.

Comment: Thank you Gokul vivid. Thats a great piece of info. Happy coding.