# How to share text of a label from iPhone app to facebook?

Tags: iphone, swift, facebook, uilabel, xcode7

I have written a simple Xcode project in swift for my iPhone . I am trying to send the text of my label to facebook using facebook share option .

Below is my code

```
 import UIKit
import Social

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var musicDescription: UILabel!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

  }

  @IBAction func faceBookShareButton(sender: UIButton) {
    if SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeFacebook) {
      let fbShare:SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)

      let text = musicDescription.text

      fbShare.setInitialText(text)


      self.presentViewController(fbShare, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else {
      let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Accounts", message: "Please login to a Facebook account to share.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

      alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
      self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

  }
```

}

But i am not able to see the text of the label in my facebook timeline. Someone guide me here . Why is the text not posting in facebook ?

Edit:Update 
I downloaded FBSDK files and added them to my project . I imported FBSDKShareKit into my ViewController.h file.

Here is my code

```
 @IBAction func faceBookShareButton(sender: UIButton) {



 if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL(string: "fb:")!) {
  var content: FBSDKShareLinkContent = FBSDKShareLinkContent()

  var Subject: String = String(format: "FBSDKShareKit is an alternative to this issue")

  content.contentTitle = "FBSDKShareKit"
  content.contentDescription = Subject

  var dialog: FBSDKShareDialog = FBSDKShareDialog()
  dialog.fromViewController = self
  dialog.shareContent = content
  dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogModeWeb
  dialog.show()
}
```

I am getting an error "Use of unresolved identifier FBSDKShareDialogModeWeb"
.
Anyone help please !

Comment: Are you facing this problem when FB app is installed ..? if it so check this one [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37320157/i-cant-share-a-content-from-my-ios-app-to-the-facebook-when-facebook-app-is-ins/37324241#37324241)

Comment: Why am i not able to send the text ? Is there any requirement that we need to use latest version of facebook in iPhone?

Comment: @Gokulvivid First i logged into my facebook account . Then i ran my app in xcode . Its just showing blank empty lines .

Comment: Because FB addd some privacy policy's [Check](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#control),it does't want its developer's add pre-filled text.If we want to share some text better go with FBShareKit as suggested in the above link.

Comment: if possible add the screenshot of FBsharedialogue which showing empty lines

Comment: Hi @Gokulvivid  . I want to implement FBShareKit . I don't know anything about pod files. How do i create pod files and use FBShareKit

Comment: @Gokulvivid I have used FBSDKShareKit in my Xcode. I am getting an error called "Use of unresolved identifier FBSDKShareDialogModeWeb".  I tried changing the mode to FBSDKShareDialogModeFeedBrowser,FBSDKShareDialogModeBrowser, FBSDKShareDialogModeShareSheet and FBSDKShareDialogModeWeb. But none of them is working .

Comment: Check my answer it may be help-full.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check return value of `setInitialText(_:)` method.

That function can return `false`. Apple document describes following.

> Return Value
>
> Returns a Boolean value indicating whether the text was successfully set.

Comment: I checked the return value of the method . I got true as the return value .  Why am i not able to pass the text value ?

Comment: Did you check ```musicDescription.text``` is nil ?

Comment: The label has a valid text . Its not nil. I printed those values in Xcode as well.

Comment: Were you able to pass the text value from your app to facebook timeline ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Using **FBSDKShareKit** is not an complete alternative but it helps to show your pre-filled content on the share dialog screen.
2. For basic check the following link [cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/).Open your terminal *install cocoapods*

   > $ sudo gem install cocoapods

   1. open your project directory,like this **eg:** *cd/desktop/TestSwift*,
   2. Then to create pod file in your project after opening your project directory add the following line `pod init` this will create a podfile inside your project
   3. Open the podfile in **TextEdit** from finder.to install FBSDK add `pod 'FBSDKShareKit'` the entire podfile will look like this

      ```
      platform :ios, '8.0'
      use_frameworks!

      target 'TestSwift' do

         pod 'FBSDKShareKit','~> 4.8.0'
         pod 'FBSDKCoreKit','~> 4.8.0'

      end

      target 'TestSwiftTests' do

      end

      target 'TestSwiftUITests' do

      end
      ```
   4. Now in your terminal inside your project directory type `pod install` add hit enter this will install all the pod's added in your podfile.

      ```
      Installing FBSDKShareKit (4.8.0)
      ```

      **NOTE:** After installing pod in your project `.xcworkspace` file will be created. Instead of using `.xcodeproj` you have to use `.xcworkspace` for further process of your project
3. Since we are using swift we have to add **Bridging Header** to over project.it helps in adding **Objective-C** frame work in **swift** project.
4. **How to create bridging header:** Use `Command ⌘ +  N` the under `ios-source` choose header file name it as *BridgingHeader.h** select location and then create it.
5. Then import your pod-file inside the bridging header file it should look like as follows

   ```
   #ifndef BridgingHeader_h
   #define BridgingHeader_h

   #import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
   #import <FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h>

   #endif /* BridgingHeader_h */
   ```
6. Now we have successfully created bridging header to make sure your bridging header is added successfully open `Targets` then select your target open `Build Setting`tab in search bar type bridging.In search result under **Objective-C BridgingHeader** you should have your **ProjectName/BridgingHeader.h**

[image]

7. Now add the code in your button action as follows:

   ```
    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL(string: "fb:")!) {
           let content : FBSDKShareLinkContent = FBSDKShareLinkContent()

           content.contentURL = NSURL(string: "https://google.com")
           content.contentTitle = "Test"
           content.contentDescription = "FBSDKShareKit is an alternative to this issue"
           content.imageURL = NSURL(string:"https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/10/01/21/39/background-image-967820_960_720.jpg")

           let ShareKit: FBSDKShareDialog = FBSDKShareDialog()
           ShareKit.fromViewController = self;
           ShareKit.shareContent = content
           ShareKit.mode = FBSDKShareDialogMode.FeedBrowser
           ShareKit.show()
    }
   ```
8. **Use of unresolved identifier FBSDKShareDialogModeWeb** to fix this replace `dialog.mode` as follows

   ```
    ShareKit.mode = FBSDKShareDialogMode.FeedBrowser
   ```

I'am using .FeedBrowser,because is working fine for me.

**FBShareDialogue:**

[image]

**FBTimeline:**

[image]

Now we got everything in timeline.Title,Description,Image,SiteURL.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gokul :)

Comment: When i gave the command pod install in terminal i get this error [!] Unable to add a source with url `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` named `master`.
You can try adding it manually in `~/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.

Comment: Make sure you have done everything correct,if it so try this command in terminal `sudo xcode-select -r`   command above resets it to the default command line path. and try again