# Making Facebook posts in SpriteKit Game

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit, social-framework

i probably have a pretty stupid question. I work on a SpriteKit game and i want users to be able to share their Highscores on Facebook and Twitter.
The posts should contain a text and an image.
The code i have works with Twitter but not with Facebook and i have no clue why..
Here is the Facebook part:

```
#import <Social/Social.h>
...

SLComposeViewController *facebookSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook];

 facebookSheet.completionHandler = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
        switch(result) {
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                break;
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                break;
        }
    };


[facebookSheet setInitialText:[_playerName stringByAppendingString: @" has a new Highscore"]];

[facebookSheet addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:_HighscoreImage]];

 UIViewController *controller = self.view.window.rootViewController;
    [controller presentViewController:facebookSheet animated: YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

1. If FB app is installed you can't share pre-filled text
2. To solve this we can go for FBSDKSharKit.Install FBSDK pod file.

   ```
   if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL(string: "fb:")!) {
       let content : FBSDKShareLinkContent = FBSDKShareLinkContent()

       content.contentURL = NSURL(string: "https://google.com")
       content.contentTitle = "Test"
       content.contentDescription = "FBSDKShareKit is an alternative to this issue"
       content.imageURL = NSURL(string:"https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/10/01/21/39/background-image-967820_960_720.jpg")

       let ShareKit: FBSDKShareDialog = FBSDKShareDialog()
       ShareKit.fromViewController = self;
       ShareKit.shareContent = content
       ShareKit.mode = FBSDKShareDialogMode.FeedBrowser
       ShareKit.show()
   }
   ```
3. For detail description on using ShareKit check my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482579/how-to-share-text-of-a-label-from-iphone-app-to-facebook/37519979#37519979).

Comment: Damn, I just found out that pre filling text is agains Facebook`s Platform Policy. Thank you anyway.